# How can I add Part# Amounts when they are in multiple columns in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum, addition

I have 4 lists of part#s and each one has a column for an amount. The part#s may or may not be repeated in each list, but what I want is one big list of every distinct part# with the total amount that was in each column. I'll show you an example.

```
Part# Amt Part# Amt Part# Amt Part# Amt
A     0   A     1   A     1   A     2
B     0   B     2   C     4   B     5
C     1   C     0   D     0   C     0
D     4   D     3   E     0   D     0 
E     7   E     6   F     4   E     3
F     4   F     0   G     3   F     5
G     2   G     0   H     5   G     6
H     6   H     2   I     0   H     0
I     2
J     6
K     3
```

And then I would like my final column to be like this:

```
Part# Amount
A     4
B     7
C     5
D     7
E     16
F     13
G     11
H     13
I     2
J     7
K     3
```

What is the best way for me to go about doing this? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you have the latest version of Excel (2013+) pro plus edition, you might be able to make use of the Data Models and the PowerPivot add-in [(MS:Create a Data Model in Excel)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-Data-Model-in-Excel-87e7a54c-87dc-488e-9410-5c75dbcb0f7b).
However, the following should work regardless of the version, and even tried/tested in LibreOffice Calc.

Assuming that you have your existing data in the columns `A:H`, and that you already have the complete list of Part# in Column `I`, you could use the following formula (modify to suit dataset) into `J2:J12`

```
=SUMIF($A$2:$A$12,I2,$B$2:$B$12)
 +SUMIF($C$2:$C$9,I2,$D$2:$D$9)
 +SUMIF($E$2:$E$9,I2,$F$2:$F$9)
 +SUMIF($G$2:$G$9,I2,$H$2:$H$9)
```

copy the formula down, and it should incrementally change the `I2` references appropriately, until you get to the final formula inside `J12`

```
=SUMIF($A$2:$A$12,I12,$B$2:$B$12)
 +SUMIF($C$2:$C$9,I12,$D$2:$D$9)
 +SUMIF($E$2:$E$9,I12,$F$2:$F$9)
 +SUMIF($G$2:$G$9,I12,$H$2:$H$9)
```

This yields the following results:

```
Part# Amount
 A     4
 B     7
 C     5
 D     7
 E     16
 F     13
 G     11
 H     13
 I     2
 J     6
 K     3
```

This solution is based on known inputs.
For something dynamic, you might need to get into a VBA/Macro, or some other database tool like SQL or Access.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have 4 such lists, then the easiest way will be to

1. Copy-paste all the lists into a single list
2. Create a second list of distinct parts, by using the REMOVE DUPLICATES button on the Data Tab to make the list of parts distinct
3. Use a SUMIFS() function to sum up the data from the first list to the second list

Here's an image with the example and formula:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant solution, to be sure, but:

```
=SUMIF($A$2:$A$12,A2,$B$2:$B$12)+SUMIF($C$2:$C$9,A2,$D$2:$D$9)
+SUMIF($E$2:$E$9,A2,$F$2:$F$9)+SUMIF($G$2:$G$9,A2,$H$2:$H$9)
```

Just put A-K in the first column and the above formula to count to sum.